# How to create first openstack conjure-up one machine instance

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

After the `conjure-up openstack` installed, how to launch the first instance?  Is the image support only downloaded from http/https? (local .iso not supported?) Are there any simple steps for the first start-up from Horizon?

I have created an instance from build-in image "trusty-lxd". It seems it's running, but can't connect to console, also ping the given IP no response, test1 trusty-lxd 10.99.0.25 m1.medium - Active nova None Running 54 minutes

Comment: I have create an instance from build-in image "trusty-lxd", seems it's running, but can't connect to console, also ping the given IP no response,

test1 trusty-lxd  10.99.0.25 m1.medium -  Active  nova  None  Running  54 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ssh into a seperate machine to run conjure-up and you deploy spells such as openstack-novalxd to localhost and you want to be able to access things like the openstack dashboard.

The simplest way to accomplish this is on your local machine run the following:

```
$ sudo apt install sshuttle
$ sshuttle -r <remote-host-ip> <subnet-of-localhost-deployment>
```

The subnet of localhost is going to be what conjure-up configured the network bridge for. By default this is set to 10.0.8.1/24. Lets also say the remote host’s ip is 172.16.0.5 so you’ll want to do the following

```
$ sshuttle -r 172.16.0.5 10.0.8.1/24
[local sudo] Password:
client: Connected.
```

It will then ask you to enter your sudo password and once complete will let you know that the sshuttle is connected. From there you can open your web browser and access the horizon dashboard as if it was running on your local machine.

Assuming the openstack-dashboard was deployed to a machine whose ip is 10.0.8.15, you could run:

```
$ xdg-open https://10.0.8.15/horizon
```

Otherwise if you're running conjure-up on your laptop, then those lxd container addresses should be accessible.

Reference: http://conjure-up.io/docs/en/users/#running-conjure-up-remotely